# Eclipse IDE freezes on ctrl+shift+t

Tags: eclipse, freeze

A couple of weeks ago, my Eclipse started to freeze when I click on Ctrl+Shift+T to "Open Type". It would unfreeze after 10-15 seconds, but it's really annoying. This initially happened on my Eclipse Photon, so I upgraded to Eclipse IDE 2018-12, but still, the issue persists. I even deleted my .metadata folder from my workspace and re-created the workspace from scratch, but no luck. I do, however, have Eclipse Oxygen, which is pointing to a different workspace (older one), and I don't have such issues there. Even when I try to ctrl+click on a method, I get a freeze. I can't figure out what Eclipse is doing in the background to try to troubleshoot. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: How many projects and libraries are in your workspace? Maybe Eclipse is just taking that long to search all those for possible references, definitions or subtypes. What happens when you open the same workspace with Oxygen? (First create a backup of the .metadata folder)

Comment: I backed up the metadata folder and opened the workspace with Oxygen. No issues there. All my 34 projects are opened, and I am able to ctrl+shift+T and ctrl+click on a method without any freezes. I guess the workspace settings are not the issue here, but something in the newer versions of Eclipse.

Comment: Do you see this issue also with a new workspace (deleting the `.metadata` folder instead of using _Window > Preferences: Java: Rebuild Index_ is not recommended)? Do you have any additional plug-ins installed?

Comment: I deleted my .metadata folder in my attempts to fix the issue, I guess that qualifies as a "new workspace". I 'm currently re-setting my workspace settings, to get it in the state as it was before I delete the .metadata folder. I have 4 plugins installed: JBoss tools, Subclipse, Epic Perl and SPKet (JavaScript editor). I have the exact same setup on my Oxygen eclipse, no issues there whatsoever

Comment: Deleting the `.metadata` folder is not a good idea and not the same as using a new workspace. Can you reproduce the problem with Eclipse without additional plug-ins and a new workspace? If yes, enable _Window > Preferences: General > UI Responsiveness Monitoring_ to get more details.